# How Can I Make A Deep Copy of a Groovy ConfigObject?

Tags: groovy

How Can I Make A Deep Copy of a Groovy ConfigObject? I see that I can make a shallow copy of the object with .clone(), but I want to make a full deep copy.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with @HappyCoder86 answer is it assumes all config key / values are strings. If some of your config values are objects / closures (common in grails) below solution wont work.

Below solution may be slow but would work if you have values of type other then string

```
   static def deepcopy(ConfigObject orig) {
        ConfigObject copy = new ConfigObject()
        orig.keySet().each { key ->
            def value = orig.get(key)
            if (value instanceof ConfigObject) {
                value = deepcopy(value)
            }
            copy.put(key, value)
        }
        return copy
    }
```

Comment: This performs a shallow copy of maps. I've added another case to the if conditional to clone maps: `else if (value instanceof Map) { value = value.clone() }`

Answer (score 0):

```
ConfigObject config = new ConfigSlurper().parse originalConf.toProperties()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ConfigObject clonedConfigObject = new ConfigSlurper().parse("${originalConfigObject.prettyPrint()}")
```

Won't work with entries having Class or Closure values types.
But will work with Lists and Maps.